# if defined in C struct

Tags: c

Can if defined (XX) be placed inside a struct/union in a **header file**?

```
struct
{
 int i;
 #if defined(xx)
 int j;
 #endif
}t;
```

I am dealing with a large file base of .c and .h files and I need to know the possible cons of this type of usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While completely valid, a definite con to using this is any time you need to use `t.j` you would also have to surround it with your `#if defined(xx)` otherwise you will invoke compiler errors

Comment: @Aniket Weird browser bug turned my edit into a new answer post

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. The preprocessor can be used for anything, no need to feed it C. The cons of this useage are, that you have a struct which changes size depending on wether xx is defined or not. This is asking for trouble, because a library built with this define and somebody using this library without the define are having different structs....

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor directives such as `#if` can be placed anywhere in your program.  They have no actual relationship to the C code (or anything else) that is present in the text (except comments), since they are processed before the compilation phase.  You can do stupid things like the code below, although it is generally a bad idea.

```
int foo(int x)
{
#if defined MONKEY
    return 0;
}

int bar(int x)
{
#endif
    return x;
}
```